# remove an element created with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the wrapper element and it won't work

```
var $self = $("#hello");
var $selfWrap = $("<div class='myclass1' ></div>"); 
$self.wrap($selfWrap);
$selfWrap.remove();
```

I know that I can just

```
$(".myclass1").remove();
```

but i won't let jquery fetch for the DOM  while I already have it in $selfWrap

Comment: `$selfWrap` isn't the same as the DOM object that's wrapping around `$self`, it's just being used as a template in this case.

Comment: `.remove` - are you trying to remove the $selfWrap and $self or just unwrap?

Comment: @roasted Not exactly. `.wrap()` returns the originally selected element (`$self`), so calling removing on `$selfWrap` at that point would only remove the original `$self`

Comment: @Ian you are correct!

Comment: @roasted It's one of those controversial things to me - which elements to return from `.wrap()` - that I always forget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also `unwrap`.

```
$self.unwrap();
```

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: Not sure if he wanted to remove the whole element or just trying to unwrap the div that he wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to **remove the $self and $selfWrap** or just trying to unwrap the div that he wrapped.

Try using `.parent()` to remove the `$self` and `$selfWrap`,

```
$self.parent().remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) ?

Then this will do it : `$self.unwrap();`

It removes the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.